# How to host jar file on my Apache webserver?

Tags: java, apache, ubuntu, jar, centos

I have a .jar application that I'm able to run on my local OSX machine.

However, I want to host it on my server (running CentOS or Ubuntu) so that my team member can access the application as well.

My team member would then access it from their browser and by entering my server IP address.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host your application over IP. You can run your application on your local machine on a different port. And expose the port to public in your router config, so that any other person can access your application using yor IP.

For example, if your IP address is 172.30.96.102, launch your application on port 8888 say, then the other team member can access your application using 172.30.96.102:8888.

To know how to open ports to public access, see the below link

http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router

Comment: Hi Anirudh, unfortunately the teams are on different locations and it would take a while to apply for ports or firewalls to be opened to do what you suggested, we usually go down this path which is to host applications on the shared server and team members are able to access them regardless their location, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

copy the .jar file to the server and run it like this:

`java -jar <name of file>.jar &`

where .jar is the name of your application.
run with `sudo` if you want the process to run as the root user.

This will run the file as a background process on the server so it doesn't kill it when you exit.
if it runs and doesnt go back to terminal, just press enter again.

also make sure you install java on the server.

`sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk`

Dont forget to open any ports that are being used by your app.

Comment: Hi Ninjakitteh, I have installed java-1.7.0-openjdk on my machine but I was unable to run the jar file with the above command. I got an error saying "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.". A quick googling returned me a command to run "export DISPLAY=:0.0" but I'm now getting "Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.". Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not too sure what would be causing it, but it sounds like you have a GUI program you are trying to run on the server. if this is the case, you may need to split your program up into a server side app and a client side app to run it.